# R Copy and paste frequency table values

Tags: r, frequency

I have a 7 rows table with 4 columns (overarching) of categorical type where each one has 4 values: Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Agree, and Strongly Agree. It looks like this:

[image: Categorical Table]

I have 7 frequency tables, for each row. This frequency table corresponds to the first variable (freq_table). This is the frequency table.

[image: Frequency Table]

I have this for loop trying to copy and paste the number based on the column name, but I'm not able to make it. Are you able to help me?

```
freq_table <- data.frame(table(data_process$OverarchingImproveRelationships))

for (string_name in names(freq_table)) {
  if (freq_table[string_name] = 'string_name') {
    overarching[, string_name] <- freq_table[string_name]
  }
}
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(overarching)` and a couple of examples of the frequency tables, `dput(freq_table1)`, etc.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to obtain?  I.e. what's the desired output?  It looks sort as if you're trying to recreate the original table from a summary that you made from the original table... somewhat circular.  If you could clarify with a worked example it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `data.table` and without the need of an empty "overarching" table. We just define your frequency tables and add them in a list. Then we `transpose` those tables and bind them together.

```
# example with 3 frequency tables, representing each row
row1 <- data.frame(Var1 = LETTERS[1:4], Freq = 1:4)
row2 <- data.frame(Var1 = LETTERS[1:4], Freq = 2:5)
row3 <- data.frame(Var1 = LETTERS[1:4], Freq = 3:6)

# add your frequency tables in a list
dflist <- (list(row1, row2, row3))
# provide the row.names for each frequency table
names(dflist) <- c("row1name", "row2name", "row3name")

library(data.table)

results <- rbindlist(lapply(dflist, transpose, make.names = 1))
# as data.table does not support row.names
# we convert it back to a data.frame and provide the row.names
results <- as.data.frame(results)
row.names(results) <-  names(dflist)

results

#          A B C D
# row1name 1 2 3 4
# row2name 2 3 4 5
# row3name 3 4 5 6
```